# Equinumerous sets: Prove that for all natural numbers $ n $ and $ m $, if $ I_{n} \sim I_{m} $ then $ n=m $.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose A and B are sets. We’ll say that A is equinumerous
with B if there is a function f : A → B that is one-to-one and onto. We’ll write
A ∼ B to indicate that A is equinumerous with B. For each natural number n,
let $I_n = \{i ∈ Z_+ | i ≤ n\}$. A set A is called finite if there is a natural number n such that $I_n ∼ A$. Otherwise, A is infinite.

Prove that for all natural numbers $ n $ and $ m $, if $ I_{n} \sim I_{m} $ then $ n=m $. [hint: use induction on n]

From http://users.metu.edu.tr/serge/courses/111-2011/textbook-math111.pdf page definition from 306 and question from 312.  Given the definition of $I_n$ I would have thought this would just simply follow by definition.  Can anyone comment why it is even necessary to prove this?

Also please give solution using the suggested induction on n.

Comment: Give the relevant definitions, suggestions, etc _here_, instead of referring to some website ($I_n$ is not defined on the page you mentioned).

Comment: sorry gave the relevant definition.